# Django hacer group by con suma

Tags: django

Tengo un modelo de Movimientos de almacen, quiero sacar las existencias por almacén de un artículo.
La consulta SQL es:

```
select  almacen_id, sum(uentrada), sum(usalida) from Almacen_movimiento 
    where articulo_id = 2
    group by almacen_id
```

Yo intento esto:

```
mv = Movimiento.objects.order_by('almacen').annotate(ent=Sum('uentrada')).annotate(sal=Sum('usalida')
```

(como es un procedimionto dentro del modelo articulo y uso _set no hace falta la clausua where.

La cuestión es que algunos almacenes salen dobles, cuando no debería.

¿ Como puedo hacerlo ?

Answer (score 0):

puedes intentarlo de esta manera

```
Movimiento.objects.order_by('almacen').annotate(
     ent = Sum('uentrada'),
     sal = Sum('usalida')
)
```

Comment: Igual, no lo hace bien. Un artículo tiene 3 movimientos en 2 almacenes distintos. Pues sale 2 veces el mismo almacén, y 1 el que es distinto. Debería salir solo 2 movimientos ya que solo hay 2 almacenes.

Comment: Agregale .distinct()

Comment: Sigue igual. Es increible. He mirado la docu, y he visto algo de "values" ¿ sabrías decirme de que trata ? en ingles no me entero mucho. Y google traduce regular.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta esto:

```
Movimiento.objects.filter(articulo_id=2).values('almacen').annotate(
    ent=Sum('uentrada'),
    sal = Sum('usalida')
).order_by('almacen')
```